# Show page if page name is same as subfolder's name

Tags: php, apache, laravel

So, I have 4 folders in my public folder: js, css, images, fonts (yes, i should put all in one folder). I also have a route which is pointing to an /images page. The problem is, when I open the images page, it throws a 404 error. Are there any solutions for this, or I have to rename the folder or the page. (The page names will be dynamic, so if the user creates a page named "anotherPage" it will be /anotherpage.)

routes.php

```
Route::get('/{pagename?}', 'PageController@index');
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: can we see some code please? Itll help us to understand what youre trying to do.

Comment: You can't have a `example.com/images` URL that sometimes points to your `images` folder and sometimes points to a PHP or HTML page. Is it the question?

Comment: The question is, can I have the same page name as my subfolder's (images) name

Comment: After seing your edit, you could try to point all `/images/(.*).jpg` (and `png`, etc.) to `images` folder, but `/images` with nothing more behind to your HTML/PHP page/controller. (I don't know how does Laravel router work.)

Comment: when you say 403 error , have you checked permission of your images folder . Next do you have 'images' route name same as your folder name?

Comment: sorry, 404. and yes, the route name is the same as the folder name

Comment: Ok try changing and check again.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly.

You can have same name as your folders BUT, if a file with name `upload` exist within the folder `upload` (upload/upload.ext). It will always direct to folder not the file and try to get `upload/index.ext`.

This is a default yet confusing behavior which can lead to ambiguous results.
Never use same folder names and files.

Comment: It also throws the error if the folder is empty, or it has files with different name.

Comment: of course it will through a 404 if the rule doesn't match as there is no file to return. that's what happen when the path in not present.

Answer (score 0):

The route for the images page must be defined before the {pagename} route.